# How to record your interior scene?

Tags: camera

I am wondering if anyone knows how to record your entire project instead of one shot scene. Example below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B8Rh9c2DMs

I would appreciate if you can share the steps or if you have any video where I can learn this.

Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender.SE. Have you tried setting keyframes on the camera? If you mean the cuts, the simplest way would be to set keys on two adjacent frames with the camera far apart.

Comment: I need the camera to go to different rooms and floors as video. Did you look at the example attached? Thanks

Comment: Yes, have you read my comment? " ***Have you tried setting keyframes on the camera?*** "

Comment: I really do not know how to do it. I would be grateful if you can tell me in steps that I can check it.

Comment: Found a Video on youtube. Thanks for your help